# How do I allow concurrent reads and writes to a serialized binary file

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a module to serialize a generic list into a binary file. If I wanted to allow multiple users to write to a file at the same time, or multiple users to read from the file at the same time, what do I need to do? I know there is a FileAccess enumeration I can pass to my filestream, but I am not sure what the limitations are, or what to set it as.

If FileAccess is for something else, what other solutions are there? (no databases)

```
   Dim _Format As New BinaryFormatter

    Public Function SavePack(Of T)(Filename As String, Output As T) As Boolean

        SavePack(New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create), Output)

    End Function

   Public Function SavePack(Of T)(Stream As FileStream, Output As T) As Boolean

        Dim Result As Boolean = False

        Try

            _Format.Serialize(Stream, Output)

        Catch ex As Exception

            Stream.Close()

        End Try

        Return Result

    End Function
```

Comment: You can tinker with the FileShare arguments to get the operating system to stop complaining when you do this.  It is however not something you should actually try.  If a read happens to coincide with a write then it will get random garbage, part of new and part of old data.  You only get an exception when you're lucky.  A FileStream is *not* a substitute for a dbase engine.

Comment: I guess what I am looking at doing is creating an object store such as MondoDB, which stores physical BSON objects (Binary JSON). I just wish I knew how they handled the users. Don't get me wrong, I love SQL databases, but like the idea of what these NoSQL (Not Only SQL) databases are doing.

Comment: Opps. Thanks for the answer on Fileshare too Hans. I appreciate the help..